# How to convert MySQL Time to ISO 8601 Duration with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table storing time durations in the format HH:MM:SS

I would like to convert these MySQL time entries into ISO 8601 time durations using PHP.

So for example, I would like to convert an entry in the database of 00:01:23 to be output as PT1M23S

And in cases where the duration is in hours an entry such as 01:23:04 would be output as PT1H23M4S

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `explode` and a bunch of `if`s and string concatenations is all you need

Comment: FWIW, simply having MySQL do a `SELECT CONCAT('PT',TIME_TO_SEC('myTimeColumn'),'S')` _technically_ produces a valid ISO8601 duration, since the spec allows e.g. seconds > 60

Comment: Can you give more example.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, especially to A C and Rishi for sample code for me to study and learn from! In the end I went with Jiri's suggestion by doing a PHP explode on the colons and a ltrim to remove any leading zeros. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
 <?php 
   $time = "1:23:4";
   $converted = date('\P\TH\Hi\Ms\S', strtotime ($time));
   $converted = str_replace (['00H','00M','00H','0'],'',     $converted);
   echo $converted;
 ?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/730495

Comment: These are time **durations**; I _think_ strtotime will fail if the hours are greater than 24

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways to approach this, but a simple (and hopefully readable) approach would be something like:

```
 function hmsTo8601($hmsTime)
 {
      $ret = "PT";
      $arr = array_reverse(explode(':',$hmsTime));
      $ct = count($arr);
      if ($ct >= 3) $ret.=$arr[2].'H';
      if ($ct >= 2) $ret.=$arr[1].'M';
      if ($ct >= 1) $ret.=$arr[0].'S';
      return $ret;
 }
```

...of course you'll want to **add some error checking** in a production environment, and this assumes that your table maxes out with hours.